# Openstack: Why the interfaces in router section are down? and how do I bring it up?

Tags: openstack

my lab:

- 1 VM for MAAS 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for JUJU 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 4 VM for OPENSTACK 400GBx2 HDD + 16GB RAM

All services on nodes are all correctly installed via, Openstack has been correctly deployed via Juju.

[image]

For the problem on neutron-gateway I've opened a post here, but I'm waiting any suggest.

The instance has been created with its own interfaces but on the router section the interface is down and it's impossible to ping the container.

[image]

While using Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot that are in UP status. thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that followed this
[suggest](https://github.com/openstack-charmers/openstack-bundles/issues/28)